# Get value of a cell in a row in a datagrid in the 'Paint' function?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework

I have inherited `datagridcolumnstyle` and in the Paint function I need to do some things based on the cell in the row being rendered.

So for example I have the following:

```
row 1: color1, name, last name
row 2: color2, name2, last name2
row 3: color3, name3, last name3
```

the name and last name columns need to be painted in the colour defined in the colour column.

So when the `datagridcolumnstyle` in relation to name2 is being drawn I need to be able to do something like:

```
protected override void Paint( Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight )
{
Color color = (Color)GetRow( rowNum ).GetCell(color1).Value;
}
```

Comment: I've never used the [DataGridColumnStyle Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle(v=vs.71).aspx). The example linked doesn't build under any WinMoble version I have. Do you have a better reference? What is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what this is or how to get it to work, but here is the example shown from Microsoft's [DataGridColumnStyle Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) example:

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum,
    Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight) {
  DateTime date = (DateTime)GetColumnValueAtRow(source, rowNum);
  Rectangle rect = bounds;
  g.FillRectangle(backBrush, rect);
  rect.Offset(0, 2);
  rect.Height -= 2;
  g.DrawString(date.ToString("d"), this.DataGridTableStyle.DataGrid.Font, foreBrush, rect);
}
```

Based on that snippet of code, I'd say the reason for this tool is to read the value from the cell at the coordinates supplied and change the color based on that value.

So, if the value were invalid, you could paint the cell Red.

If the value were not saved, you could make the font bold.

But, the example I posted is VERY NOT for Windows Mobile!

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution, one that I have used, is to pass a reference to the owning DatGrid in to your custom `DataGridColumnStyle` object when you create it.  This can either be done via the constructor, or via a property.  Then you can access the full row during the `Paint`.